# Откуда происходит чередование мягкого знака и гласных и/я

Tags: чередования, мягкий-знак

В русском языке встречаются равнозначные слова, где гласный «и» или «я» заменяется мягким знаком. Часто в именах, но не только:

- песня — песнь
- София — Софья

Связаны ли эти чередования между собой и как это называется?

Не зная терминологии, не получилось ничего полезного нагуглить, кроме рассуждений о равноценности этих написаний имен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **София и Софья**

Чередование ***ИЯ/ЬЯ*** связано с разной фонетической **транскрипцией** слов: **Соф(ийа)** и **Соф(йа).**  Во втором варианте мягкий знак используются при обозначении звука ***Й*** в позиции между согласной ***Ф*** и гласной ***Я***. Звук ***И*** в имени София находится в **ударной** позиции, а при переходе ударения на первый слог чередуется **с нулем** (беглая гласная ***И***).

**Чем отличаются имена Софья и София**

**Софи́я** (Софья; др.-греч. σοφία — «мудрость, разумность, наука») — женское  имя греческого происхождения. Греческий вариант был принят без существенных фонологических изменений во многие языки, в южнославянских и восточнославянских и балтийских языках есть **София** (Софија), София (София) и **Софья** (Софья).

**[Происхождение имени Софья](https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Sofia/proishozhdenie-imeni.html?imya=%D1%EE%F4%FC%FF)**

```
 У Романовых имя Софья сохранило статус одного из 
 распространенных ДИНАСТИЧЕСКИХ имен. Если до XIX столетия 
 имя Софья носили в основном представительницы знатных 
 фамилий и аристократических кругов, то в этот период оно 
 начинает активно распространяться и среди простого народа. 
 К концу XIX века имя стало 20-м по популярности и 
 употреблялось уже не только среди дворян, а также и в 
 других сословиях. В советский период это имя было одним из 
 самых непопулярных, вернулось оно в обиход лишь к началу 21 
 века.
```

Если сравнить с именем ***Марья — Мария,*** то там история похожая, но все-таки на такая же.  Имя Мария — древнее еврейское "любимая". В христианской традиции имени добавили образ "госпожа". А вот Марья — **РУССКИЙ вариант** имени. Иван-да-Марья, Марья Искусница, Марья-Краса- длинная коса, Марья Моревна — **сказочные образы из нашего прошлого.**

**2. Песнь и песня**

Здесь история другая: сначала была ***песнь,*** а ***песня*** появилась значительно позже. Фонетика такая: чередование гласного с нулем звука на конце слова, при этом мягкий знак обозначает мягкость согласного ***Н***. В слове ***песня*** добавлен гласный, так что сущ. женского рода переходит в 1-е склонение (нейтральный стиль). А сущ. ***песнь*** считается устаревшим, но может использоваться с особым **стилистическим** оттенком.

**[Словарь-справочник "Слово о полку Игореве"](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/slovo_o_polku_igoreve/597/%D0%BF%D1%A3%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8C)**

**Пѣснь.**  Словесно-музыкальное произведение, исполняемое одним голосом или хором.

```
  Начати же ся тъи пѣсни по былинамь сего времени, 
  а не по замышленію Бояню. 1. Боянъ бо вѣщіи, аще 
  кому хотяше пѣснь творити, то растѣкашется мыслію 
  по древу.
```

**[Когда возникла русская песня?](https://dzen.ru/a/ZZkWK6SvuEWxaNxG)**

Вплоть до середины **восемнадцатого века** мы не встречаем в литературе **самого слова "песня"**! Самые ранние записи того, что пелось — небольшой **сборник 1620** года, составленный англичанином Ричардом Джемсом, посланником от короля Якова к царю Михаилу Фёдоровичу.

```
Само явление существовало, но это было силлабическое 
стихосложение! Там ещё нет привычного нам 
чередования слогов ударных и безударных. Потому нам и трудно 
представить себе, как это можно ПЕТЬ? Прочесть такие стихи 
можно можно, а спеть — никак. Вот одна из первых известных 
нам песен (не силлабических кантов, а настоящих песен).
Елизавета Петровна, дочь Петра Великого, не афишировала 
своего авторства. Но — хорей?! Интуитивно найденный размер, 
один из пяти, которые мы сегодня считаем классическими?!
```

*Во селе, селе Покровском, /Среди улицы большой,*

*Разыгралась-расплясалась / Красна девица-душа,*

*Красна девица-душа, / Авдотьюшка хороша.*

**ВЫВОД**

```
  Связаны ли эти чередования между собой и как это 
  называется?
```

Казалось бы, заданные темы можно объединить и рассматривать как нечто цельное. Но нет, чередования здесь разные, как и история отдельных слов. В русском языке происходит **ассимиляция** иноязычной лексики, в том числе имен,  в соответствии с  культурными и языковыми традициями.

А связывает эти темы буква  ***Ь***, который в древнерусском языке назывался ЕРЬ. ***Ь*** и ***Ъ*** обозначали очень короткие (редуцированные) гласные, которые были утрачены в середине XII — начале XIII века. В современном языке это разделительный Ь (***Софья***) и Ь, обозначающий мягкость согласного (***песнь***).

Answer (score 2):

Ааа, конкретика нужна!

А явление называется вариантные формы окончаний.

Приведённые два примера

*песня — песнь*

*София — Софья*

имеют разное объяснение.

Песня - нейтральное (словесно-музыкальное произведение для пения разным числом лиц; жанр вокальной музыки),

а песнь - устаревшее и высокий стиль (по отношению к песне); раздел эпической поэмы; церковное (Херувимская песнь).

София и Софья, Мария и Марья, Наталия и Наталья - это варианты одного имени; пишутся, как в паспорте, однако

мягкий знак в имени как бы упрощает его, снижает пафосную ноту.

> У большого количества слов есть вариантные формы на *-ие* и на *-ье*,
> например: проклят*ие* - проклят*ье*, спасен*ие* - спасенье,
> признан*ие* - признан*ье*, молчан*ие* - молчан*ье* и т. п. При этом
> формы на *-ие* являются общеупотребительными и стилистически
> нейтральными, а формы на *-ье* характерны для разговорной и
> поэтической речи.

Однако только *гавканье, кваканье, харканье, хрюканье, чавканье, чваканье, карканье* и т. п. - как сниженная лексика.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы объяснил на примере варения-варенья.

Варение - это процесс варки, производство на огне и тп. А варенье - это результат действия, название или именование продукта.

Поэтому воскресение - это процесс, а воскресенье - это название явления или упрощенное названия дня недели, который назван так в честь большего - воскресения.

София - мудрость, Софья - имя данное в честь мудрости-Софии. Ну то есть в греческом, возможно, они совпадали, но в русском языке произошло такое деление на само понятие и производное имя-название данное в часть этого понятия.

Пение - это сам процесс - пение птиц, главное слово "пение", а пенье - это пенье соловья, то есть "соловей, который поёт", конкретизация, кто делает, а не что или каким образом делает.

Но по определённым причинам, это не обязательное какое-то употребление, а на уровне ощущений, пение - более пафосно и больше внимания привлекает, потому что напоминает церковное написание, а пенье - это как более сленговое, прозвище, разговорное, со снижением акцента на звучании или чистоте произнесения, написания словоформы.

В общем, это какой-то способ вычленения единичных явлений из общего, разделение непрерывного пения на треки - пенье, наборы из песен.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151751/discussion-on-answer-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.